# Signed Flutter android app can't access Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have created a signed release of my Flutter android app. It cannot access Firebase. In debug it works fine.

I have signed the app using Google Play App Signing and have already added the corresponding SHA-1 from Google Play Store to Firebase but to no avail. This is the solution stated in most similar questions.

I have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

in AndroidManifest. Any idea what else could be wrong? How could I debug this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you sign your app with key provided by google? 
Did google sign it after you uploaded it?
The key you must put in firebase is the key which was used to sign the app.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad I have clarified the question. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there is this [Bug](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2124). When using `android.enableR8.fullMode=true` in gradle.properties, firebase auth breaks.